# Explanation of this LINQ expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would be grateful if someone could explain this following LINQ expression:

```
Endpoint adapter = (from adap in this
                    where
                        (endpointName == DEFAULT_ENDPOINT_NAME && adap.IsDefault) ||
                        (endpointName != DEFAULT_ENDPOINT_NAME && adap.Name == endpointName)
                    select adap).FirstOrDefault();
```

I can pretty much get the gist of this, I just need help with the `from adap in this` section.  I would've expected this would be selecting from the current class - but I can't find anything within the current class that's a collection.  Could you point me to where the data is likely to be coming from, `adap`?

Comment: What does the type specified by "this" look like? I suspect it implements IEnumerable, IQueryable....etc.

Comment: Debug it and use F11 - step into everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class the code resides in implements `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` as that is needed for it be to able to call the [IEnumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) or [IQueryable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) method.

Comment: Not necessarily. It could implement `IQueryable<T>`, or it could have a `Where` method as an instance method, or there could be other extension methods involved. There has to be a `Where` method *somewhere*, but there's no guarantee that it's `Enumerable.Where`.

Comment: I knew about the `IQuerable.Where`, but not of the instance method. Is it possible to have a `Where` instance method that you can use in the asked expression?

Comment: Absolutely - basically the query expression is *just* translated as per my answer, and the rest is up to normal C# rules.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now - the class inherits from List<EndPoint> but I still can't figure out how this gets populated

Comment: @m.edmondson What do you mean? Somewhere, you are populating the list!

Comment: @m.edmondson: If it derives from `List<EndPoint>` then it implements `IEnumerable<EndPoint>`, so it'll be using the extension method of `Enumerable.Where`.

Comment: @OskarKjellin: If you want some *really* wacky stuff, have a look a [my blog post on odd queries](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/29/odd-query-expressions.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This is a [*query expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx). The C# compiler basically translates it to:

```
Endpoint adapter = this.Where(adap => (endpointName == DEFAULT_ENDPOINT_NAME && 
                                       adap.IsDefault) ||
                                      (endpointName != DEFAULT_ENDPOINT_NAME &&
                                       adap.Name == endpointName))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

It's likely (but not required) that `Where` is an [*extension method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) call - probably  [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) or [`Queryable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344863.aspx). If you could show us the declaration of the type this call resides in, it would make it clearer.

Basically once you've applied the "pre-processor" step, it should be clearer what's going on. In particular, if you type:

```
this.Where
```

into Visual Studio and hover over "Where", what does it show?

EDIT: Now we know that you're deriving from `List<Endpoint>` (which I'd frankly advise against, to be honest - favour composition over inheritance; deriving from `List<T>` is almost always a bad idea), it's really calling `Enumerable.Where`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you can select from this I would say.